# Save selenium python to s3

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-s3

I am trying to determine the most pythonic way to save a selenium screenshot to S3. I really would like to avoid having to write the selenium screenshot to disk and then loading and saving it to S3. However I do not think it is possible to save selenium screenshots as a variable. Below is the function I have came up with so far. Can I somehow save it directly to the location using boto?

```
def screenshot(request):
    conn = S3Connection('########', '########')
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket')
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = 'lab3'
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) # optional
    driver.get(request)
    driver.save_screenshot(request + '_toS3.png') # would rather save to s3
```

Note: Running on Apache webserver utilizing django

Answer (score 5):

```
import boto3
import io
from selenium import webdriver


S3_Client = boto3.client('s3')
chrome_path = 'path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chrome_path)

driver.get('www.example.com')
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
in_memory_file = io.BytesIO(screenshot)
S3_Client.upload_fileobj(in_memory_file, 'mybucket', 'screenshot.png')
```

Updated code in response to Addison:

```
import boto3
import io
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/chromedriver')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

driver.get('https://www.example.com')

# The driver will scroll to the bottom. This is a bug that has yet to be fixed
# This brings the driver back up to the top of the page
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)

with io.BytesIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png()) as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, 'mybucket', 'screenshot.png')

# optional 
driver.close()
```

Comment: I have not used the io package, would it be better to do it using `with` in order to close the in memory file? I don't want to run into memory issues after taking a few hundred screenshots.